# How can I compare "today" (NSDate) to a formatted string date (dd/MM/yyyy)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, compare, nsdate

I'm new to iOS programming and I've been looking a lot for a way to compare "today" (an NSDate) to a formatted string date (dd/MM/yyyy).

I've found some good answers with the NSDate's `earlierDate`, `laterDate` etc. but the code doesn't seem to work in my project.

here it is :

```
// [book quandd]  is the string :    25/02/2011  (or whatever dd/MM/yyyy date)

NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

if ( [[dateFormat dateFromString:[book quandd]] isEqualToDate:today]) {
    NSLog(@"Dates are equal");
}
if ( [[dateFormat dateFromString:[book quandd]] earlierDate:today]) {
    NSLog(@"earlier");
}
if ( [[dateFormat dateFromString:[book quandd]] laterDate:today]) {
    NSLog(@"later");
}
```

Whatever I do and whatever the date in `[book quandd]`, the console always writes "earlier" and "later", as if they were later and earlier at the same time than *today*.

Where is that "bug" coming from ?

Is there some easy/easier way to compare the *today* date with *26/02/2011* for example ?

Comment: NSDate is an *exact time*.  The odds of two times being equal is vanishingly small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `timeIntervalSinceNow:` to get the diff from the necessary date.

You should also try to get the difference between them and then convert to a string.

Comment: Thanks, but when I do that (with sinceDate:today), this is what I get with an NSLog(@"%f",dateTime); : dateTime = -36331460.303964 and numbers like that o_O

Comment: U get the response in seconds, u then have to convert them into days or whatever unit that u want.

Comment: Thanks, with a little bit of work to compare the values, I think I got it to work :)

Answer (score 1):

An NSDate includes both date and time.  No two NSDate values will be equal unless the times are identical down to the millisecond (if not finer).  When you do `[NSDate date]` you get the exact time of "now", while if you use NSDateFormatter to convert a string to date (with no time value) then midnight is used.

If you want to see if two NSDates fall on the same day you can use NSCalendar & NSDateComponents.  Or you can "cheat" and format both dates to a date string with no time value and compare the strings.

```
- (void) CompareDate:(NSDate*)date1 toDate:(NSDate*)date2 {
    NSDateFormatter* fmt = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [fmt setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
    // Note that you should set the appropriate timezone if you don't want the default.
    NSString* date1Str = [fmt stringFromDate:date1];
    NSString* date2Str = [fmt stringFromDate:date2];
    switch ([date1Str compare:date2Str]) {
        case NSOrderedAscending:
            NSLog(@"Date 1 is earlier");
            break;
        case NSOrderedSame:
            NSLog(@"Dates are equal");
            break;
        case NSOrderedDescending:
            NSLog(@"Date 2 is earlier");
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

    if ( [[dateFormat dateFromString:[book quandd]] compare:today]==NSOrderedSame) {
        NSLog(@"Dates are equal");
    }
    if ( [[dateFormat dateFromString:[book quandd]] compare:today]==NSOrderedAscending) {
        NSLog(@"earlier");
    }
    if ( [[dateFormat dateFromString:[book quandd]] laterDate:today]==NSOrderedDescending) {
        NSLog(@"later");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I see what you meant (there were some extra "[") but it's only working for earlier and later, weird... Anyway, I think the timeIntervalSinceNow: with the seconds values are working ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to check return value of the earlierDate with one of the dates referred. Ex: if([date1 earlierDate:date2] == date1)

Answer (score 0):

Your "bug" happens because laterDate and earlierDate return the date object that is either earlier or later. The return object is always nonnil, so both if statements evaluate to true. The correct way to use them is this way:

```
NSString *book = @"19/08/2014";

NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:book];
if ( [date timeIntervalSinceDate:today] == 0) {
    NSLog(@"Dates are equal");
}
if ( [date laterDate:today] == today ) {
    NSLog(@"earlier");
}
if ( [date laterDate:today] == date) {
    NSLog(@"later");
}
```

Alternatively, I've used timeIntervalSinceDate, which returns the seconds between the first date and the second date.

```
NSString *book = @"19/08/2014";

NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:book];
if ( [date timeIntervalSinceDate:today] == 0) {
    NSLog(@"Dates are equal");
}
if ( [date timeIntervalSinceDate:today] < 0 ) {
    NSLog(@"earlier");
}
if ( [date timeIntervalSinceDate:today] > 0) {
    NSLog(@"later");
}
```